# how can i import meteor-roles in typescript?

Tags: meteor, typescript, meteor-accounts

I'm writing a angular2-meteor application with typescript using angular2-meteor 0.5.4 and angular2 beta17.

I'm using `accounts-password` meteor package with with `angular2-meteor-accounts-ui` for ui representation.

I also installed the meteor package `alanning:roles`.

now I need to import `Roles` in typescript and i fail to do so because it doesn't contain a typescript definition file.

I searched on google and I found https://github.com/meteor-typescript/meteor-typescript-libs 
which container typescript definitions for many packages including Roles.

is this the way to go? am I missing something.

since I'm new to meteor and typescript i need reassurance that i'm following the right path.

thank you!

Comment: There is now an npm package for this: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/meteor-roles

Answer (score 4):

import your Roles like so

```js
import { Roles } from 'meteor/alanning:roles';
```

Next, you need to add / update your custom typings file (meteor.d.ts in my case, which is autoloaded by Meteor)

```js
declare module "meteor/alanning:roles" {
  export module Roles {
    function createRole(roleName: string): string;
    function deleteRole(roleName: string): void;
    function addUsersToRoles(users: any, roles: any, groups?: string): void;
    function removeUsersFromRoles(users: any, roles: any): void;
    function userIsInRole(user: any, roles: any): boolean;  //user can be user ID or user object
    function getRolesForUser(userId: string): string[];
    function getAllRoles(): Mongo.Cursor<RolesDAO>;
    function getUsersInRole(roleName: string): Mongo.Cursor<RolesDAO>;
    var GLOBAL_GROUP: string;
  }
}
```

Comment: Instead of writing a comment `//user can be user ID or user object` you should define that in the function signature. That's what TypeScript is for after all.

Answer (score 3):

There is a simpler way to import meteor packages in typescript. Most of the types are defined here

> https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/tree/master/types
>   https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/tree/master/types/meteor

Install NPM module that has types defined.

```
meteor npm install --save @types/meteor-roles
```

Import the types in your modules

```
import { } from '@types/meteor-roles';
```

Now, you can use Roles type for methods like addUsersToRoles() etc.